# Carbon: displaying hours and minutes?

Tags: php, laravel, frameworks

I have recently been using Carbon to display humanized time strings, but for some reason I can only get it to show the main factor, for example, I have a date that it needs to show how long until that date is. So for example, if its 6 days, 4 hours and 32 minutes away from now, it currently only displays '6 days'.

How would I go about getting it to display the hours too, and possibly the minutes? It's kind of horrible looking when it only gives you the days, and many people may want to know more like the hours and seconds?

I can't find anything on the Carbon documentation for this. I am using it inside a laravel 5.3 view if that's even relevant.

Heres my code:

```
{{ \Carbon\Carbon::createFromTimeStamp(strtotime($item->created_at))->diffForHumans() }}
```

Comment: Try this `->format('j M Y , g:ia')`

Comment: As @Zl3n said, you have to use format because diffForHumans' purpose is to give an approximation easily read by humans

Answer (score 12):

You shouldn't use `diffForHumans()`in this case, because it returns only a string on which one can no longer work. This is an end result.

It is better to work with a `Carbon` object, like this :

```
$created = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromTimeStamp(strtotime($item->created_at));
```

And then, add this in the view :

```
{{ $created ->diff(\Carbon\Carbon::now())->format('%d days, %h hours and %i minutes'); }}
```

You can extend for a larger period :

```
$created ->diff(\Carbon\Carbon::now())->format('%y year, %m months, %d days, %h hours and %i minutes');
```

**EDIT (according to the comments) :**

If you do :

```
$diff = $created->diff(Carbon::now());
var_dump($diff);
```

You get this result :

```
object(DateInterval)[113]
  public 'y' => int 0
  public 'm' => int 0
  public 'd' => int 6
  public 'h' => int 4
  public 'i' => int 32
  public 's' => int 29
  public 'f' => float 0.397424
  public 'weekday' => int 0
  public 'weekday_behavior' => int 0
  public 'first_last_day_of' => int 0
  public 'invert' => int 0
  public 'days' => int 6
  public 'special_type' => int 0
  public 'special_amount' => int 0
  public 'have_weekday_relative' => int 0
  public 'have_special_relative' => int 0
  // results depend of the current time
```

From there, you browse the elements to create the best answer to your needs.

Comment: Why do you do ->diff(Carbon::now()) and not directly format the date ?

Comment: @AlexvanVliet To get the current time with the `Carbon` object. Have you another suggestion ?

Comment: This isn't good if the minutes are equal to 0, it's not very well formatted, I need a day to do it with an organised format.

Comment: For example let's say if I had 1 day exactly, I need it to say '1 day'.

Comment: @AshSmith What you ask is not written in the original question. I have changed my answer so that you can achieve your goals.

Answer (score 5):

#### Show only Hours:Minutes (11:11)

To display only `Hours:Minutes` you can use:

```php
$curr = \Carbon\Carbon::now()->format('H:i');
echo $curr; // 11:11
```

If you have to set a timezone you have to use the timezone function. You can pass to these function your timezone `timezone('Your/Zone')`

```php
$curr = `\Carbon\Carbon::now()->timezone('Europe/Amsterdam')->format('H:i');
echo $curr; // 12:11
```